# c shell script: find directory and rename the output of find

Tags: shell, find, rename

i am still new in this shell script. I have  a task that given to me which i have difficulty to execute it.
The task is i have a lot of directory which is based on ddmmyy.

```
03Mar2014  08Aug2013  11Jan2015  16Jan2014  22Feb2014  26Mar2014  
03Nov2013  08Jan2014  11Jul2013  16Jul2013  22Jul2013  26Oct2014  
03Oct2013  08Jan2015  11Nov2014  16May2014  22Mar2014  26Sep2013
```

The task is to make the directory to mmyy.

So far, my code is

```
foreach file(`find . -type d | awk -F/ 'NF == 3'`) 
echo $file
set newmove = `echo $file | cut -c 1-2,5-`
echo $newmove
mv $file $newmove

output:
for find . -type d | awk -F/ 'NF == 3':
./24Jan2015/W51A
`echo $file | cut -c 1-2,5-`
./Jan2015/W51A
mv $file $newmove
mv: cannot rename ./24Jan2015/W51A to   ./Jan2015/W51A: No such file or directory
```

but the script didnt work. 
Do you guys have any idea how to do this?

Comment: *Must* you use c-shell for this, or could you alternately use a POSIX shell or Bash?  Also, When you want to make directories "mmyy", do you really mean "mmmYYYY", like the input list you're showing? [CSH programming is sometimes considered harmful.](http://www.bmsc.washington.edu/people/merritt/text/cshbad.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the issue is you're renaming the file but actually tryng to rename the directory, hence the error.

As I understood the idea is to rename the folders in the current working directory to the desired format and by this actually merge the content of the folders from the same mmYYYY format to the new one (since *11Jan2015*  and *16Jan2014*  will be renamed both to *Jan2014*)

you can try this:

```
foreach dir ( `ls` )    
   set newdir = `echo $dir| cut -c 3-`

    mkdir -p $newdir
    mv -f $dir/* $newdir
    rmdir $dir
end
```

-p will create the folder and will do nothing if the folder already exists.

Some assumptions:

1. The folders are at the same place which is `pwd`
2. There are always two leading digits in date
3. You want to merge the folders content of the same mmYYYY format
4. The files with the same name in different folders will be overwritten
5. There are only folders in pwd (add check if it's not the case)

In case these folders are in different places (which is not the case according to your output: *./24Jan2015* ) and collision is not an issue - the code should be changed to :

1. Use find
2. Create the new folder with the correct path

No merge and overwrite will occur, so 1,3,4 and 5 are not relevant.

UPDATE:
After additional input - if I understand correctly your find is looking only for the folders of depth 3. I can't say why but you can achieve the same much faster with

```
find . -type d -mindepth=2 -maxdepth=2
```

The output is the list of the folders that have subfolders.

Then you need to get the second folder's name (assuming it will always be of the expected format).

```
set olddir = `echo $file| cut -f 1-3 -d '/'`
set newdir = `echo $olddir  | cut -c 1-2,5-`
```

and finally

```
foreach file(`find . -type d -mindepth=2 -maxdepth=2`) 
    set olddir = `echo $file| cut -f 1-3 -d '/'`
    set newdir = `echo $olddir  | cut -c 1-2,5-`

      mkdir -p $newdir
      mv -f $file $newdir
end
```

This will also handle the case if two folders were found under the same path.

UPDATE 2:

Since the script will run on Unix - the following updates should be made:

- Original find was returned since unix find lacks the mindepth/maxdepth options
- We should try to remove the olddir to cleanup the empty folders - it will fail if the folder is not empty but the script should continue to run

> ```
>  foreach file(`find . -type d | awk -F/ 'NF == 3'`) 
>      set olddir = `echo $file| cut -f 1-2 -d '/'`
>      set newdir = `echo $olddir  | cut -c 1-2,5-`
>      set dir_name=`basename "$file"`
>
>          
>       if ( -d "$newdir/$dir_name" ) then
>           mv -f $file/* $newdir/$dir_name/
>       else
>          mkdir -p $newdir
>          mv -f $file $newdir
>       endif
>      rmdir $olddir
>  end
> ```

Comment: thanks. based on my script, i already using find so that have different path. then how to make directory if they have same directory after remove the dd?

Comment: If you want to create it where you found the original folder - you don't have an issue then, since the paths are different. Otherwise if you want to move to specific place - use the script with `$some_place/$new_dir` instead of `$new_dir` where `some_place` is the specific path

Comment: Updated. Pay attention however that you don't find different paths but only  the folders in the pwd with folders in them.

Comment: im trying using find . -type d -mindepth=2 -maxdepth=2 but i got error find: bad option -mindepth=2
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
thats why im using find . -type d | awk -F/ 'NF == 3'

Comment: Well, use your version then. Just wondering - are you running on Unix?

Comment: Well, that explains a lot. Did it work after replacing the `find` with your version?

Comment: yeah..i think it works. can u explain to me a bit why it doesnt work out at my version?

Comment: Great. You was trying to move the folder x from A to B like so  `mv ./A/x ./B/x`.  This was not possible since B does not exist yet. All I did was to create the folder prior to move and then execute `mv ./A/x ./B/` .

Comment: Just a suggestion, being on unix was the important part of the question, consider adding the appropriate tag next time - this would reduce the time to answer and will eliminate non-compliant solutions (like using bash or non-existing options). By default it will be assumed you're running on Linux.

Comment: hi again..after exec this mv -f $file $newdir it will create double directory.. means that ./Jan2015/W51A/W51A..how to make it only make just ./Jan2015/W51A?

Comment: I think there is a typo, try  set olddir = `echo $file| cut -f 1-2 -d '/'`

Comment: thanks. if i have two with same directory ./Jan2015/W51A..how can i move it to ./Jan directory?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow. What is the issue?

Comment: i have two directory ./08Jan2014/Wfdrd and ./09Jan2015/Wfdrd.. after execute the script, the ./09Jan2015/Wfdrd not move to ./Jan2014, only ./08Jan2014/Wfdrd that move to ./Jan2014

Comment: Updated. Note that the directories would be merged. If you want different names - add some suffix to new_dir

Comment: how to merge the content of ./09Jan2015/Wfdrd to ./08Jan2014/Wfdrd? since the script currenlty, it will merge content of ./09Jan2015/Wfdrd to ./Jan2015 not to ./Jan2015/Wfdrd

Comment: hi...im sorry..i need to ask some question regarding this..what if the $file/* already in  $newdir/$dir_name/? i dont want the $file/* replace the file in $newdir/$dir_name/...please advice

Comment: Probably you need to check wether the $newdir/$dir_name/$file already exists ( `if ( -d "$newdir/$dir_name/$file" )`)

Comment: hi..the output for $file is ./17May2014/W45AF02_P0NP59.00.. so `( if ( -d "$newdir/$dir_name/$file" )` isnt it will check the /Jan2014/W51A/17May2014/W45AF02_P0NP59.00? 
i want to check if /Jan2014/W51A/exfil already exist in copy_datalog, it will not move while the rest of file in /Jan2014/W51A will move `mv -f $file/* $newdir/$dir_name/` ? sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: hi... i want to rename the duplicate files by adding the no of copy of filenames. how can i do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I really think c shell is the wrong tool for just about anything that involves programming.  That said, this looks like it would do what you want with only a little help from an external tool:

```
#!/bin/csh

foreach file ([0-9][0-9][A-Z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
  set new = `echo $file:q | cut -c 3-`
  if ( -d "$new" ) then
    echo "skipping $file because $new already exists"
    continue
  endif
  mv -v "$file" "$new"
end
```

Note the glob that matches your list of directories to rename.  This script isn't bothering to confirm whether the matched files ARE in fact directories, so if there's the possibility they might not be, you should account for that somehow.

Note that we are using a back-quoted expression to use an external tool, `cut` to grab a substring from each directory name.  We use this (as you did in your question) because CSH IS NOT A PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE, and has no string processing capabilities of its own.

The `if` statement within the loop will skip any directory whose target already exists.  So for example, if you were to go through the top row of your input in your question, 26Mar2014 would be converted to Mar2014, which already exists due to 03Mar2014.  Since you haven't specified how this should be handled, this script skips that condition.

Comment: illegal option of --v.

Comment: @wina, `--v` is not the option I used. Try a single dash. It's a valid option in BSD, OSX and Linux. If you're using something else, please say so, or just drop the option.

Comment: im using single dash v. the error came out is  
illegal option of --v